# I need to set a losing condition for a simple game I am making in Unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, conditional-statements, new-operator

I am working on a simple mobile game in Unity. There is a cannon at the bottom of the screen and you shoot small bullets at moving platforms at the top of the screen. For my lose condition I need to say something along the lines of "If 5 bullets are above 5f on y axis" then game over.

I know how to make the game restart when the game ends and I have tried making it so that when you run out of ammo and not all of the platforms are destroyed, the game ends. But the problem with this is that if you have one bullet left and you shoot it, the game end program gets triggered right when you shoot the last bullet. So even if the last bullet hits the last platform, the game still ends and restarts. On the first level you have 5 bullets and there is one platform.

I am thinking the best way to do it would be to check if all of the bullets fired are above 5f on y axis, which is above the platform target. If all 5 bullets fired are above this, then the game ends.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your suggestion makes sense! It seems like you're looking for the scenario where the player no longer stands a chance of completing their goal. So, your lose condition might be if both:

- all the bullets have passed the "point of no return" (above 5f on the y axis), and:
- there is still at least one platform remaining.